# Create script that will build sub-domain (linux/whm/cpanel) based on the values from webform

Tags: linux, cpanel, puppet, whm

I don't know whether this can be done. I need to create sub-domain in a server using puppet based on the values from a web form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you save your form data on disk, you can work with `external node classifier`s.

more info here: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.3/nodes_external.html